# Moving files with a pattern in their name to a folder with the same pattern as its name

Tags: linux, bash, shell, mv

My directory contains mix of hundreds of files and directories similar to this:

```
508471/
ae_lstm__ts_ 508471_detected_anomalies.pdf
ae_lstm__508471_prediction_result.pdf
mlp_508471_prediction_result.pdf
mlp__ts_508471_detected_anomalies.pdf
vanilla_lstm_508471_prediction_result.pdf
vanilla_lstm_ts_508471_detected_anomalies.pdf

598690/
ae_lstm__ts_598690_detected_anomalies.pdf
ae_lstm__598690_prediction_result.pdf
mlp_598690_prediction_result.pdf
mlp__ts_598690_detected_anomalies.pdf
vanilla_lstm_598690_prediction_result.pdf
vanilla_lstm_ts_598690_detected_anomalies.pdf
```

There are folders with an ID number as their names, like 508471 and 598690.
In the same path as these folders, there are `pdf` files that have this ID number as part of their name. I need to move all the `pdf` files with the same ID in their name, to their related directories.

I tried the following shell script but it doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong?
I'm trying to loop over all the directories, find the files that have `id` in their name, and move them to the same dir:

```
for f in ls -d */; do
    id=${f%?}  # f value is '598690/', I'm removing the last character, `\`, to get only the id part 
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname *.pdf -exec grep $id {} \; -exec mv -i {} $f \;
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c '
    for d in "$@"; do
        id=${d#./}
        for file in *"$id"*.pdf; do
            [ -f "$file" ] && mv -- "$file" "$d"
        done
    done
' findshell {} +
```

This finds every directory inside the current one (finding, for example, `./598690`). Then, it removes `./` from the relative path and selects each file that contains the resulting id (`598690`), moving it to the corresponding directory.

If you are unsure of what this will do, put an `echo` between `&&` and `mv`, it will list the `mv` actions the script would make.

And remember, [do not parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: You can do the shorter `for d; do` and don't forget the `.pdf` suffix in your glob `*"$id"*.pdf`.

Comment: @Freddy Thank you, I edited the answer. With that we don't even need the `[ -f "$file" ]` test before moving!

Comment: @Quasímodo the code didn't mv any file :( I'm getting this error for every ID: `mv: rename *520813*.pdf to ./520813/*520813*.pdf: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Quasímodo Is it trying to rename the files to `./520813/*520813*.pdf`?

Comment: @Birish That's because of nullglob (I guess you had no file with 520813 id in the directory, but had `520813` directory), about which I forgot. It tried to move the inexistent (literal) `*520813*.pdf` to the corresponding directory. Despite the error message, the script must have succeeded in moving the other files. Check out the edit, try it and no error should arise.

Comment: @Quasímodo still not working :( no error msg though. I need all the files with name of `*<ID>*.pdf` to go to directory with name of `<ID>` . This `ID` can be 598690 for example

Comment: @Quasímodo I'm testing your script, `d` in the first loop, `id` in the second loop are correct. the `file` value is `*520882*.pdf`. The `mv` command doesn't do anything. Does it understand that `*520882*.pdf` is wildcard and not the exact file name?!!

Comment: It worked! I made a very silly mistake! Let's not talk about it :|

Answer (score 1):

The below code should do the required job.

```
for dir in */; do find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*${dir%*/}*.pdf" -exec mv {} ${dir}/ \;; done
```

where `*/` will consider only the directories present in the given directory, `find` will search only files in the given directory which matches `*${dir%*/}*.pdf` i.e file name containing the directory name as its sub-string and finally `mv` will copy the matching files to the directory.

Comment: @Birish directories 508471, 598690 and rest all the sample files are in same parent directory and you need to move files having given directory name as sub-string to that directory, right?

Comment: yes they are all in the same directory. I need all the files with `*<ID>*.pdf` to go to directory with name of `<ID>` . This `ID` can be 598690 for example

Comment: This is strange. The script works perfectly for me. You are running script from directory containing all those files and directories, right?

Answer (score 0):

in Unix please use below command

```
find . -name '*508471*' -exec bash -c 'echo mv $0 ${0/508471/598690}' {} \;
```

Comment: it's not only one ID, there are 200 different IDs! With the command you wrote I need to manually change the ID 200 times. I need a command that iterates over all IDs and move them to a directory with same name

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `for` loop from the parent directory of these pdf files and directories:

```
for d in */; do
    compgen -G "*${d%/}*.pdf" >/dev/null && mv *"${d%/}"*.pdf "$d"
done
```

`compgen -G` is used to check if there is a match for given glob or not.